# Gecfofx 22.0 in C# uses lots of computer memory

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have implemented Geckofx 22.0 from bitbucket in my c# app (VS 2008). It is working well, but the only problem is memory consumption. While running app is using lots of computer memory. My app has to play some local flv as well as swf files.

Please suggest me some solutions on how can I reduce memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

You could try periodically calling nsIMemory.HeapMinimize:

eg:

```
if (_memoryService == null)
  _memoryService = Xpcom.GetService<nsIMemory>("@mozilla.org/xpcom/memory-service;1");              
_memoryService.HeapMinimize(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
           [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr process, int minimumWorkingSetSize, int maximumWorkingSetSize);


    public void ClearGarbage()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
    }
```

Comment: This answer could be improved substantially by explaining exactly what each call is for and why (you consider that) it's helpful in addressing the problem.